# FFMPEG RTMP stream Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Running into a wee issue here.
I'm trying to use an rtmp stream as an input and then outputting it to twitch.
`ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/ -f flv -c:v libx264 -c:a aac rtmp://mad01.contribute.live-video.net/app//stream_key`

The only issue with this, is that the rtmp sometimes restarts (whenever the video being sent to it ends), and after it restarts, it causes this script to output
`Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 10006, current: timestamp; changing to 10006`

This plays the first video fine, but anything after that just stops working.

I believe this would be a fine fix, if it wasn't for the fact that previous and current were ALWAYS the same value (the length of the video sent to the rtmp stream in ms). This should be the reason as of why it just stops outputting, because the current timestamp isn't incrementing at all.
The example I gave was for a 10 second video sent to the rtmp stream.
This issue disappears if the first video was like 10 seconds, and the second one is 20, and it reaches the 10s mark on the second video.

I've tried searching quite literally everywhere but couldn't even find someone with the same issue I have. Appreciate any kind of help